# no matching function for call to && no known conversion for argument 1 from

Tags: c++, arrays, class

So I've been trying to test my code in main but I can't get past this error

In my .h file I have this declared this method

```
int common(string words[], int count[], int n);
```

My .cpp file

```
int testclass::common(string words[], int count[], int n){
//code
}
```

This method will take the string and int arrays as parameters and populate them based on a known array and amount n.

For my main function I have something like this

```
testclass test
string testwords[4] = {"0", "0", "0", "0"};
int testcount[4] = {0, 0, 0, 0};
test.common(testwords[4], testcount[4], 4);
```

I've also tried to put in the arrays without initializing

```
string testwords[4];
int testcount[4];
```

I can't get past this error

```
In function 'int main()*':
error: no matching function for call to 'testclass::common(std::__cxx11::string&, int &, int)'
test.common(testwords[4], testcount[4], 3);
                                         ^
//in cpp file
note: candidate: int testclass::common(std::__cxx11::string*, int*, int)
int testclass::common(string words[], string count[], int n)
    ^
note: no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}' to 'std::__cxx11::string* {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*}'
```

Comment: Try `test.common(testwords, testcount, 4);`. Note the difference between the array and the element.

Comment: wow i feel so dumb... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Passing `testwords[4]` to the function tries to select a single word from the array. And out of bounds at that.

To pass an array as a pointer (or as `x[]`), just give the name of the array:

```
test.common(testwords, testcount, 4);
```

The array name will decay to a pointer in almost all cases, including this.

Answer (score 0):

Mistake you are making is in function call
test.common(testwords[4], testcount[4], 4);
Try this instead 
test.common(testwords, testcount,4);
But you need to pass the array size as different parameter